# Deploy an Asp.net core web api to IIS but can't access by other computer using IP:{port}/api/{controller}

Tags: sql-server, database, iis, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

I wish to deploy an asp.net core web api to IIS on a windows server. On
that windows server the api can be accessed using http://localhost:5000/api/values.

But on another computer it can't be accessed using http://MyWebsiteIp:5000/api/values.

Chrome says

> Can't access the website,ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

And the firewall I have is closed so it doesn't work too. The api connects with a SQL Server Database and when I use VS debug on my commputer IIS Express the CRUD function can work using http://localhost:53450/api/{controller}.

But when I deploy to IIS on windows server it doesn't using http://localhost:5000/api/{controller}. I have copied the Database to Windows Server and placed it in the same path with my computer.

Could you help me ?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background IIS site bindings control what URL can be used.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly use cmd to ping the IP address to make sure you have used the right IP address to access the web api.